# Fingerprint log-in not working in win10

Tags: windows-10, fingerprint

After a clean windows 10 install, I headed to `Settings->Accounts->Sign-in options` set a PIN, and then under `Windows Hello` I added a fingerprint. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

However, in the lock screen, I do not have an option to use fingerprint to log in but rather only PIN and password.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have a fingerprint device that supports Windows Hello?

Comment: I was not aware there was a need for a specific support. I used fingerprint login in win8 and win8.1 on this laptop (thinkpad s440).

Comment: Windows 8.1 fingerprint support was different

Comment: The fingerprint adding functionality worked, it asked me to swipe a couple of times and said the fingerprint was added. I supposed that was all there was to it. Are there any other steps to adding fingerprint login in win10?

Comment: I have to ask have you tried to simply scan your fingerprint?  I am pretty sure Windows Hello authentication is suppose to work passively, in that, if you had a supported camera and it detected your face it would just simply log you in.

Comment: Fair question. I did at the time, but now I tried again and nothing. I tried swiping it several times at the lock screen and at the PIN input screen and nothing happened.

According to [this guide](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/using-windows-hello-and-fingerprint-log-windows-10) (which looks a bit outdated) there should be a third sign in option, but I only get the two (pin and password).

Comment: Which leads me back to.  Does the fingerprint device support Windows Hello.  It makes no sense, but I could understand It allowing you to setup the fingerprint, but not supporting Windows Hello.  Have you look for updated device drivers for it?

Comment: It's not in the [list](http://www.windowscentral.com/here-are-all-pcs-support-windows-hello-facial-recognition-windows-10) I found for facial recognition, but according to [lenovo's page](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht103819) I suppose it should, since it's a reasonably new device (thinkpad s440). That's all the info I got on the subject.

Comment: Your device wouldn't be in a list for facial recognition due to its age, but you are not trying to get facial recognition to work, doesn't matter looks like it was a driver issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Delete the fingerprints you already registered.
- Go to the device manager and uninstall ( with deletion ) the current diver
  under "Biometric devices" even if it's the same you already had.
- Install the newest driver you can find.
- You maybe have to click the "discover new hardware" symbol in the device manager.
- Register two prints.

Now you can login with them. This way it worked for me.

Comment: Yeah it was the two prints. It doesn't say so anywhere, but there seems to be a minimum of two prints.

Comment: I was able to get it working without 2 prints. The critical step for me was to remove the existing fingerprint on the account, then add it again.

Comment: This also worked for a Win 8.1 upgrade to Win 10 (not clean install). He might have confused with the *old* fingerprint data.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you install the latest drivers. It helped me get my Thinkpad T440S running Windows 10 (Win8.1 drivers would not suffice). Even had to look for manufacturer drivers, not IBM OEM, because the latter were not out yet...

Comment: Yeah I did install the latest ones, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. What wasn't working for you before you installed them?

Comment: I reinstalled drivers and added two fingerprints instead of just one, and it seemed to be working now!

Comment: I removed one of the prints and it stopped working, so I marking the other answer as correct since it seems to be related to the number of prints.

Comment: I have the habit to define at least 2 prints, so did not encounter the same situation as you. Glad you found your way ;)

Answer (score -1):

When I had trouble signing in to Windows using the fingerprint reader, I fixed it this way:

1. Go into your control panel
2. Click on User Accounts
3. Click Programs
4. Enroll fingerprints (SimplePass)